# I can't run my games

Tags: watch-dogs

Trying to play some new games (like watchdogs,Call of Duty Advanced Warfare etc.) on Windows 7 32-bit, I'm getting the following error:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

Trying to run the application in compatibility mode has no effect. I'm guessing these games somehow rely on 32-bit DLLs which are missing from my system, and I would like to know if anyone else has encountered a similar problem, and is able to give insight as to possible solutions or work-arounds

Answer (score 4):

The error message is telling you that the software you're trying to run is not compatible to the 32 bit version of Windows.

And indeed, [Watch_Dogs](http://store.steampowered.com/app/243470/) and [Advanced Warfare](http://store.steampowered.com/app/209650/) ***are not compatible*** with 32 bit Windows.

---

Watch_Dogs:

> Minimum:
>   OS: Windows Vista (SP2), Windows 7 (SP1) or Windows 8 (**Please note that we only support 64 bit OSs.**)

Advanced Warfare:

> Minimum:
>   OS: Windows 7 **64-Bit** / Windows 8 **64-Bit** / Windows 8.1 **64-Bit**

<sub>Emphasis mine.</sub>

---

The only solution available to you, is to install a [64 bit version of Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) or [8](https://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft) over your existing installation.

Since you're reinstalling your OS, I'd recommend backing up all important data from your `C:\\` drive before they're deleted.

Comment: The good news is, that if he own Win7 legimately he can install 64 bti at no extra cost and a get disc image here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery

Comment: Depending on the age of the OP's PC, it may not be possible to run a 64 bit OS

Comment: @Robotnik. I think a PC that's too old to run a 64 bit OS is also too weak to run those games in the first place. In that case, OP would be better off playing games on consoles, but that would be a completely unrelated matter.